# Issue accessing data.json to filter new card/componet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-router, fetch-api

So I've got my page setup to bring in the id from the previous page. If I click on imaged 4 it brings up the the url (/Food/4) and so on. So I'm getting the right info from my previous page. Now the issue I'm having it using a fetch to get my data.json file to pull the info from the json to then render the info on the page based off the id. So if I click on image 4 and the 4 id is passed to my new page I want to show the data from the json file of image 4. I've tried a couple different fetch setups, even an axios setup, but I'm just at a loss. Do I need to implement the useParams? params.id? Thanks!

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import data from './data.json'

export default function Foodinfo() {

    const params = useParams()
    const [ item, setItem ] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('/data.json')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data));
    })

  return (
    <div>
        <h1>Food Info</h1>
        <img src={item.pic} />
        <Link to="/">
            <button>Menu</button>
        </Link>
    </div>
  )
}
```